I created a website using flutter and when I use it on the local server it works fine, but when I use it on a real server it does not work
I programmed a website using Flutter, but when I try to connect it to real hosting, it does not work
I have tried a lot but I do not know how to solve the problem. Can someone help me?
This is the code
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

String _basicAuth = 'Basic${base64Encode(utf8.encode('sued:suady'))}';

Map<String, String> myheaders = {'authorization': _basicAuth};

class Crud {
  getRequest(String url) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return responsebody;
      } else {}
      // ignore: empty_catches
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  postRequest(String url, Map data) async {
    try {
      var response =
          await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data, headers: myheaders);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        return responsebody;
      } else {}
      // ignore: empty_catches
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}


<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    http_response_code(204);
    exit();
}

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id55555067_sirte";
$user = "id2555567_sijhveun";
$pass = "s!rtunD6";
$option = array(
   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8"
);
$countrowinpage = 9;

try {
   $con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $option);
   $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   
   // Enable CORS
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");

   // Handle preflight requests
   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
       http_response_code(200);
       exit;
   }

   include "functions.php";
    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}


<?php 
 
  include "../connect.php" ; 
 
  $email = filterRequest("email");

  $pass  = filterRequest("pass");

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `pass` = ? AND email = ? "); 

  $stmt->execute(array( $pass , $email )) ;

  $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ; 

  $count = $stmt->rowCount() ; 

  if ($count > 0) {

    echo json_encode(array("status" => "success" , "data" => $data)) ; 

  }else {

    echo json_encode(array("status" => "fail")) ; 

  }


I created a simple login interface and expected it to log in, but it still shows an error and I don't know why the API cannot be accessed.
This error appears:
Error Catch FormatException: //sirte-un-db.000webhostapp.com/mydatabase/auth/login.php AAA
Error
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 296:3       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 893:3   defaultNoSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 866:5   noSuchMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 318:12  callNSM
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 329:25  _checkAndCall
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 494:10  callMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 498:5   dsend
packages/enter_sirte_university/custom/login_screen/form/custom_login.dart 49:19  login
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                              runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 163:18                                        handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 847:44                                        handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 876:13                                        _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 652:5                                         [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 722:7                                         callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                                  _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                                   _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 181:7                <fn>

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.6


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  awesome_dialog: ^3.2.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13


At line 49 of custom_login, are you parsing a URL? If so, it's invalid. Missing the scheme (https)?

Yes, it works perfectly, but in this project it does not work on the web. I do not know why

Print out the URL before trying to parse it. If it looks wrong at that point, figure out who's calling getRequest with that incorrect value - then figure out where it's getting that value.
